# I tried to form the code from 2d (Physics.OverlapCircle) into 3d (Physics.OverlapSphere) but it still doesnt work, can someone help me? Thanx

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new on programming and I tried to transform the code from 2d into 3d (from Physics.Overlapcircle into Physics.Overlapsphere), but it still doesn't work.
I also looked for the problem on Stack Overflow, but with this tip it also doesn't work...
I make the Controller for a grid based game... All works, but I can move through obstacles. Is it wrong to make it with Overlap Sphere? Do you have another idea? Thanx
Here is the code:

```
public class MovementPlayer1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Transform movePoint;
    public Transform forward, back, left, right;
    public Collider[] colliders;

    public LayerMask whatStopsMovement;

    void Start()
    {
        movePoint.parent = null;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //Time.deltaTime, damit es überall gleich schnell ist

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, movePoint.position) <= .05f)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) == 1f) //Mathf.Abs fragt, ob es entweder positiv oder negativ ist, bzw. falls Input.GetAxis... sich irgendwie bewegt
            {
                colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(movePoint.position + new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, 0), 0.2f, whatStopsMovement);
                if (colliders != null)
                {
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, 0);
                }
            }

            if (Mathf. Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) == 1f)
            {
                colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(movePoint.position + new Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")), 0.2f, whatStopsMovement);
                if (colliders != null)
                {
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: If your player is a `Rigidbody` than A) you should not use `Transform` to move it at all! and B) you could rather use [`SweepTest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html) to check if you hit something i you would move

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with the SweepTest! Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with the SweepTest and it worked. I don't know why it doesn't work for me with Physics.OverlapSphere. For guys who found this question, I would recommend you to do it with the SweepTest.
Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
if (colliders != null)
```

"colliders" is an array, unity doesn't like that comparison array vs null. Instead try checking the arrays size:

```
if (colliders.Length > 0)
```

For handling movement input if you insist on using transform.position, then instead of having 2 if statements I would suggest you change it to something like that:

```
void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //Time.deltaTime, damit es überall gleich schnell ist

        float movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float movementZ = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(movementX, 0, movementZ);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, movePoint.position) <= .05f)
        {
                colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(movePoint.position + newPosition , 0.2f, whatStopsMovement);
                if (colliders.Length > 0)
                {
                    movePoint.position += newPosition; 
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanx for youre answer... I understand, what you mean, but if I put it like that in the code, I can't move my character.

Comment: I make the Controller for a grid based game... All works, but I can move through obstacles. Is it wrong to make it with Overlap Sphere? Do you have an other idea? Sorry im new.

Comment: `you can't compare array with null.` ... yes you can ;) unlikely though that Unity returns `null` at this place

Comment: I phrased it a little bit weird, my bad, what I meant was that unity is complaining about this comparison so it's best to skip it and make sure it's valid using entry count.

Comment: @lars07 now you can't move your character at all?

Comment: I would also reccomend you change your movement input reading, I have edited my answer - have a look.